# Java how to print all local variables?

Tags: java, local-variables

I have a method and want to examine variables inside it without debugging - is it possible in Java?

I do not want to write tons of code like:

```
System.out.println("a: " + a);
```

I want to something like:

```
System.out.printLocals();
```

Also it should be great to have something like:

```
System.out.printMembersOf(someObjectInstance);
```

Comment: All members has been asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526826/printing-all-variables-value-from-a-class, let's keep this just for locals.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can write a method with a varargs parameter and just write:

```
dump(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, ...);
```

It's not ideal, but it will be enough in some circumstances. There's no way to automatically grab all the local variables from a method and dump them though.

You might consider some sort of bytecode manipulation (e.g. with [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/)) which could do it... but it would be pretty ugly.

Comment: BCEL hmm, ugly eh? I'd rather use dump(ar1, ar2m,..)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to have something like: `System.out.printLocals();`
>
> Also it should be great to have something like: `System.out.printMembersOf(someObjectInstance);`

Just about every Java class has a `toString` method.  You override that method, and you can get a string that represents what you're asking for.

Eclipse Helios, among other IDEs, will generate a basic `toString` method for you.

Comment: this will not work for case: `public void foo(int k, String s) { System.out.printLocals(); }` // expected output is the same as for `System.out.ptintln("k: " + Integer.toString(k)); System.out.ptintln("s: " + s);`

Comment: @denys:  You're correct.  However, there's no reason you couldn't code a toLocalString method for each of the methods you wanted local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.out.println` to print out variables. Example:

```
int i = 42;
System.out.println("i:" + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Just print them out to the debugger. ([Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html))

OR

- Print out to the console: (`System.out.println("var")`)

OR

- User [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j

Comment: On `jdb` there is `locals`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "examining" ? Try a System.out.println(yourvariable), or (yourvariable.toString()) if it's an object. It'll display it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple to read the values of local variables at runtime, even if you're a debugger. If there are no debug symbols in your class, there is no way at all to see local variables, even if you use a debugger.

The most simple solution to see the values is printing them with `System.out.println()` or to use logging ([slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)).

If you want to example local variables at runtime without changing the code, you can try [AOP](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30799) (Aspect-oriented programming). Or you can use the same [API that a debugger uses](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/) to examine the running VM.