# Retrieving variables names from a Java method

Tags: java, variables, reflection, methods

im trying to get the variable names as well as the methods called using them e.g. callMethodOne is called and passes variableOne.

The methods are in different classes and there are several methods in a class. So far I have got other information I need such as class names using reflection. Below is an example of how the methods are laid out.

```
 public class ClassOne extends ClassTwo {

    public void methodOne(){
        String variableOne = rowData.get("variableOne");
        String variableTwo = rowData.get("variableTwo");
        String variableThree = rowData.get("variableThree");
        String variableFour = rowData.get("variableFour");
        String variableFive = rowData.get("variableFive");

        callMethodOne(AnyVariable,variableOne)
        callMethodOne(AnyVariable,variableTwo)
        callMethodTwo(AnyVariable,variableThree)
        callMethodOne(AnyVariable,variableFour)
        callMethodThree(AnyVariable,variableFive)
    }

}
```

I want to know if it is possible in java to get the name of the methods called and the parameters/variable names passed in?

Comment: Local scope variable names are not persisted after compilation.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible in java to get the name of the methods called and the parameters/variable names passed in?

Comment: @Colin747: no, it's not possible, and you're doing something very wrong if you think you need that.

Comment: @McDowell: they actually are, if you compile with debug information, but I don't think it's accessible to Java code.

Comment: The thing is that the name of the variable is not nearly as important as you might think that it is, that it mostly doesn't even exist in compiled code. ***MUCH***  more important is getting a handle on a *reference* to an *object*. You may want to search this site since this same question gets asked about once a week or more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get information about the local variables using Java reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816951/can-i-get-information-about-the-local-variables-using-java-reflection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot get the names of the passed parameters in a standard Java environment.