# Can I use value of a local variable defined in a method, in other method in Java?

Tags: java

**The method is not returning the value of the local variable.**

**Can I use the value of local variable index from the following method**

```
public boolean contains(Object input) {
    int index = 0;

    while(myAsetIterator.hasNext()) {
        index++;
        if(input.equals(myAsetIterator.next())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**in this method as the index of the array of the object that I want to remove.**

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    int count = 0;
    if(o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(contains(o)) {
        genArray[index] == null;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println(count+" same elements were present in Aset. "
                + "Removed all those "+count+" elements from Aset.");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know the scope of a local variable is limited to the method it's declared in. But there might be a way that I might not now yet to make this happen without using a field/instance variable.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't get the local variable value. You may look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816951/can-i-get-information-about-the-local-variables-using-java-reflection but that would need the library to be compiled with "-g" option.

Comment: Why cant you declare index as a class variable (make it static)

Comment: if `contains()` was named `indexOf()` and returned the index, instead of returning a boolean, you could get the index by calling `indexOf()`, and then use it to set the value at this index to null.

Comment: @ClydeD'Cruz that's probably the worst advice to give. Why would two instances share the same index?

Comment: Oh I may not understood, my comment suppose you can't modify the method code.

Comment: @JB Nizet - This is a project thing and I am supposed to use only the provided fields and methods inherited/implemented from an interface that the class is implementing. I am just exploring the depths of JAVA and see is there something that I might not know. Thanks for the advise though. :)

Comment: I can complete the remove(Object o) method using other long ways. This is just much shorter (but seems like impossible) way. :)

Comment: Have a look at JonSkeet's answer. You're expecting contains() to return both true and the matching index, in that case it's not appropriate to name your method as `contains()`. `indexOf()` will be your best bet where in you get some valid index for some input match and -1 in other cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The whole point of it being *local* to a method is that it only exists within that method. The options are:

- Use an instance field, i.e. make it part of the state of the object. That's unlikely to be appropriate.
- Use a static field, i.e. make it part of the static of the type. That's almost *certainly* inappropriate.
- Change the existing method to return the information you want.
- Create a new method to return the information you want.
- Duplicate the existing code within `remove` so that you can get the index. That would be sad :(

As an example of the last two, you could write:

```
public int indexOf(Object input) {       
    int index = 0;    
    while(myAsetIterator.hasNext()) {
        index++;
        if (input.equals(myAsetIterator.next())) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public boolean contains(Object input) {
    return indexOf(input) == -1;
}
```

... then in your `remove` method, you'd use `indexOf` instead of `contains`.

Comment: Just a small correction, in case there's a match, you're not returning  updated `index` , always returning -1 :)

Comment: @Arkantos: Fixed, thanks. (In fact it would have failed to compile :)