# how to get all variable and type data in class and method using java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class and i want to find all variable and type data.

for e.g

```
class ex
{
    String A,B;
    public void method()
    {
        int a;
        double C;
        String D;
    }
}
```

so i want output like this

```
A : String
B : String
a : int
C : double
D : String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the methods `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` and `Class.getDeclaredFields()` from the Reflection API to list a class methods and attributes.

```
for (Method m : ExampleClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName() + ": " + m.getGenericReturnType());
}

for (Field f : ExampleClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + f.getType());
}
```

But you can not normally access the local variables information. In Java 8, you have access to the methods parameters using the method `Method.getParameters()`. So you could do:

```
for (Method m : ExampleClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    for (Parameter p : m.getParameters()) {
        System.out.println(p.getName() + ": " + p.getType());
    }
}
```

The parameter names are not stored by default in the .class files though, so the parameters will be listed as `arg0`, `arg1`, etc. To get the real parameter names you need to compile the source file with the -parameters option to the javac compiler.

Comment: sir i still can't get the local variable with your solution,have any idea for get the local variables sir?thanks

Comment: @hendrianto The only local variables that you can normally access are the parameters. You could get some information about the others if you compile your program in debug mode and use a bytecode library. Check [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816951/can-i-get-information-about-the-local-variables-using-java-reflection).

Answer (score 0):

check [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), you can get all the info of a class on runtime

Comment: you can't use reflection to get local variables here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reflection` to get `A` and `B` for sure. But you can't get same info for other `local` variables.

Comment: so how can i get the local variables sir?