# How to use dot operations on Strings with the same name as object?

Tags: java, object

I have two Cat objects

```
   Cat A = new Cat();
   Cat B = new Cat();
```

then I ask the user which cat he want to modify

```
   String choice = input.nextLine;
```

I want to run all my Cat instance methods on `choice` and change the object to which it refers.  For example:

```
   choice.drinkMilk(15, 2);
```

if `choice` was `"A"` it would execute `drinkMilk(15, 2)` on cat A and if it was `"B"` it would do it on B.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: Is there any way to do this without HashMap? This is for my introductory Java course and we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: You could create getters and setters in your `Cat` class.

Comment: I'm taking introduction to Java so you guys are going to have to go a little easy on me. What is map and reflection? And I have getters and setters in the Cat class but how does that help?

Answer (score 3):

When you create your cat objects, put them in a HashMap:

```
Cat A = new Cat();
Cat B = new Cat();
Map<String, Cat> herd = new HashMap<String, Cat>();
herd.put("A", A);
herd.put("B", B);
```

Then, when the user makes a selection from A or B, you can retrieve the appropriate cat to operate on:

```
String choice = input.nextLine;
Cat selectedCat = herd.get(choice);
if(selectedCat != null) {
    selectedCat.drinkMilk(15,2);
} else {
    // user made a bad selection, so let them know
}
```

If you can't use a Map, then you could use an if/else solution:

```
String choice = input.nextLine;
if("A".equals(choice)) {
    A.drinkMilk(15,2);
} else if("B".equals(choice)) {
    B.drinkMilk(15,2);
} else {
    // user made a bad selection, so let them know
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using HashMap because we haven't really learned that yet and I don't know if my professor allows it.

Comment: Edited to use if/else solution.

Comment: You can't use reflection to access local variables. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24094467/481248

Answer (score 2):

You can add another variable in your cat class called `string id` which is then initialized after you create the cat object;

```
Cat A = new Cat();
A.id = "cat1";
Cat B = new Cat();
B.id = "cat2";
```

then you can do an if statement from the users input with the cat id:

```
String choice = input.nextLine;

if(choice.Equals(A.id))
//execute cat1
else
//execute cat2
```

Comment: Thats what I was doing before but that doesn't really work for me because it gets really complicated and lengthy for one of the things I have to do.

And besides what's the point of the id system? This is what I did

              if(choice.Equals(A)
              A.drinkMilk
else 
B.drinkMilk

Comment: @Natantantan how many cat objects are you planning to make? if it is a lot then a Map is a way to go.

Comment: @Natantantan No that wont work because you are comparing an `object `with `string` which will always return false.

Comment: Well in my real problem it's not cat objects its collection objects and there's only two but one of the things i have to do is move one thing from one collection to another collection and that requires a lot of nested if loops

Comment: @Natantantan what do you mean by collection objects. if it is not the car object paste you snippet of code above.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
HashMap<String, Cat> cats = new HashMap<String, Cat>();
```

this creates a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
Cat A = new Cat();
Cat B = new Cat();
Cat C = new Cat();
//    ... and so on.

cats.put("A", A); //assigns the appropriate cat object to the key ("A")
cats.put("B", B);
cats.put("C", C);
//    ... and so on for more cats.    

String choice = input.nextLine();

Cat cat = cats.get(cats.get(choice));
if(cat!=null)
cat.drinkMilk(15,2); //get the appropriate cat object.
```

Comment: You should check if the user has made a valid choice - otherwise you get a `NullPointerException`.