# Java, cannot tell what is going wrong? VERY basic code

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the whole of the "f" variables in one line of code.. f obviously standing for female but when I use the way I have code it is showing errors?

I am sorry, i am  beginner.

```
import java.util.*;

class university {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Person2 mPerson, fPerson = null;`

        String fFirstName, fSurname, mFirstName, mSurname;
        int fAge, mAge;

        System.out.println("Please enter the firstname of your favourite female author");
        fFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her second name");
        fSurname = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her age");
        fAge = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the firstname of your favourite female author");
        mFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her second name");
        mSurname = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter her age");
        mAge = scanner.nextInt();

        fPerson = new Person2(fFirstName, fSurname, fAge);

        System.out.print(fPerson);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? How is `fPerson2` defined?

Comment: There is no "fperson2"

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: Gee, sorry. How is `person2` defined? If you don't take the time to format your code, things will get read mistakenly.

Comment: I searched ["how to print a class in Java"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526826/printing-all-variables-value-from-a-class) and guess what?

Comment: This line System.out.print(fPerson); won't print the variable, you need to override the toString() method

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that you did not read any tutorial about Java and you try to solve the upcoming issue blinded.

The problem you face is that you did not declared a place where the computer gets the information you expect him to have. The coding is not a magic thing, you get what have you wrote.

What you are missing is implementation of `toString()` method in your `Person2` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
 return fFirstName 
}
```

Do not loose more time to solve platform issues and try to read a the [trial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Implement toString() method for Person class, just printing the object won't print the values.

```
public String toString() {
   //format the way you want the values to be printed
   return fFirstName + " " + fSurname + " " + fAge;
}
```

Comment: The class name is Person2 and you need to add @Override