# Equals based on all fields in static utility function using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, equals

I have a class `MyObject` with a number of private fields. The equals method is based on all fields and uses reflection since I don't want to list every single field (cf. [Printing all variables value from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526826/printing-all-variables-value-from-a-class/1526843#1526843)):

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( !(o instanceof MyObject) ) {
        return false;
    }

    MyObject myO = (MyObject) o;

    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            if ( ! Objects.equals(field.get(this), field.get(myO))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now I would like to use this method in a number of classes while not having to copy&paste this function all the time. Therefore I wrote a static function in a utility class

`public static boolean allFieldsEqual(Object t, Object o)`

and replaced the above `equals` function by

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return allFieldsEqual(this, o);
}
```

The problem is that `Field.get(Object o)` throws `IllegalAccessException`s since the fields are private (which I would not like to change).

Do you have an idea how to put the `allFieldsEqual` functionality into a static method inside a utility class?

Comment: You might like [Objects.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: I think that if an object contains "itself", this *might* lead to a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: It leads to a `StackOverflowError` - because `Objects.deepEquals(a,b)` calls `a.equals(b)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen `Objects.deepEquals` does not compare the fields of the given objects. It only does an `Arrays#deepEquals` if the objects are arrays, and uses `firstObject.equals(secondObject)` otherwise.

Comment: @jpmath My comment with the `StackOverflowError` referred to *your* approach in general (and not to Joop Eggens proposed method). You somehow would have to make sure that "cycles" are detected in your recursive equality test. It *might* be possible to solve this, maybe with an `IdentityHashMap`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you try to call `get()` on the field, set it to accessible first:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        if ( ! Objects.equals(field.get(this), field.get(myO))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        field.setAccessible(accessible);
    }
}
```

Comment: (And set it back to `false` after. Best effort.)

Comment: Putting back every field with a private accessibility without any control is not a good idea to me. Storing the initial value, putting it to accessible true and in the end restore the initial value is much more appropriated : what about public fields otherwise (ok, we shouldn't see any but we know it happens).

Comment: Thank you, `field.setAccessible(true)` did it. `field.isAccessible()` is stored and restored.