# Is it possible to print various instance variables and their values of an object in Java, without explicitly using instance variable?

Tags: java

Coming from `JavaScript`, I find it surprisingly hard to do so. In `JS` it was as easy as writing object's name in console. One way is to override `toString()`. But it is too tedious since I have to print all the instance variable separately? Am I right? If yes, is there another way?

Comment: toString though is the best way. But since you have to print all the instance variables separately (not sure why)  you can use their getter methods.

Comment: You can use Lombok for this as described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40716165/1997376)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you right, but you can use some tools for override `toString` method easily, for example [`ToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) method [`reflectionToString`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString-java.lang.Object-)