# Convert DTO to List of parameter

Tags: java

```
public class CreateCustomerRequest {
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String gender;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String mobileNo;
}
```

I have above Request DTO. What I need when I will get this request then I need to `convert this DTO with List<String> fields;`
Where `List<String> objects` contains `{fName, lName, gender, address1, address2, mobileNo}`

Please suggest how I will achieve this. Not getting any idea.

Comment: Do you mean that u need to convert the attributes of this DTO to a list?

Comment: Right, so do you just mean `Arrays.asList(fName, lName, gender, ...)`?

Comment: @Shiladittya Reflection API is useful to get declared field of DTO class

Comment: @Phil Yes correct but I need in dynamic way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing all variables value from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526826/printing-all-variables-value-from-a-class)

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic way"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on reflection, if you make fields public the below code work, if you want to make them private instead of setting field you can convert it by constructor.

```
public class CreateCustomerRequest {
    public String fName;
    public String lName;
    public String gender;
    public String address1;
    public String address2;
    public String mobileNo;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    List<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add("fnameValue");
    param.add("lNameValue");
    param.add("genderValue");
    param.add("address1Value");
    param.add("address2Value");
    param.add("mobileNoValue");
    CreateCustomerRequest object = convert(param, CreateCustomerRequest.class);
    System.out.println("Gender : " + object.gender);
}

public static <T extends Object> T convert(List<String> param, Class<T> clazz) throws Throwable
{
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    T result = (T) ctor.newInstance();
    Field[] fields = result.getClass().getFields();
    if(fields == null)
        return null;
    for(int i =0;i<fields.length;i++)
    {
        if(fields[i].getType().equals(String.class))
        {
            if(param.size() > i)
                fields[i].set(result, param.get(i));
        }
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Cheers.

**EDIT**

For making DTO class fields private and read them via getter method, I edited  my answer to support it.

Changes :

1. Convert result.getClass().getFields() ---> result.getClass().getDeclaredFields() to able read privatye fields.
2. calling fields[i].setAccessible(true) before setting value to field.
3. Read field value via getter --> System.out.println("Gender : " + object.getGender());

so new code of DTO class is :

```
public class CreateCustomerRequest {
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String gender;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String mobileNo;

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }
    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }
    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }
    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }
    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }
    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }
    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }
    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }
}
```

and converting code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    List<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add("fnameValue");
    param.add("lNameValue");
    param.add("genderValue");
    param.add("address1Value");
    param.add("address2Value");
    param.add("mobileNoValue");
    CreateCustomerRequest object = convert(param, CreateCustomerRequest.class);
    System.out.println("Gender : " + object.getGender());
}

public static <T extends Object> T convert(List<String> param, Class<T> clazz) throws Throwable
{
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    T result = (T) ctor.newInstance();
    Field[] fields = result.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    if(fields == null)
        return null;

    for(int i =0;i<fields.length;i++)
    {           
        if(fields[i].getType().equals(String.class))
        {
            if(param.size() > i)
            {
                fields[i].setAccessible(true);
                fields[i].set(result, param.get(i));
            }
        }
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for this. Is there any way for getting the value also

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty You're welcome. I updated my answer for getting value (in proper way) If I understand your comment correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have object and you want to get fields of class of that object, you can use reflection in following way to get list of those fields,

```
Field[] fields = createCustomerRequestObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
//OR
//Field[] fields = CreateCustomerRequest.class.getDeclaredFields();
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (Field field : fields) {
    fieldNames.add(field.getName());
}
System.out.println(fieldNames);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[fName, lName, gender, address1, address2, mobileNo]
```

Comment: Thanx for this. Is there any way for getting the value also