# Scala extend trait field not found

Tags: java, scala, reflection, traits

I have a scala trait with a public UUID that has a default value:

```scala
trait pet {
    var uuid_ : UUID = UUID.randomUUID
}
```

now I am creating multiple classes, also in scala:

```scala
class dog extends pet {
    var foo = 1
}
class cat extends pet {
}
class fish extends pet {
}
```

After that I created a method in Java (old project with both languages mixed).
Here the snipped with my problem. In the variable `somePet` is an instance of `dog`, `cat` or `fish`. But it is not clear what of them exactly:

```java
// printing all variables in the console for human testing
Serializer.printAllFields(somePet);

// The somePet Variable must be a pet
if(!pet.class.isAssignableFrom(somePet.getClass()))
    throw new Exception("Not a pet.");

// get the UUID of the pet
UUID uuid_;
try {
    Field f = pet.class.getField("uuid_");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    uuid_ = (UUID) f.get(somePet);
}catch(Exception e){
    // no uuid found
    throw e;
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: uuid_
```

And the stacktrace points on the line with `Field f = pet.class.getField("uuid_");`.
But what is wrong with the code?
An alternative I thought was replacing this exact line with:

```java
Field f = ntObj.getClass().getField("uuid_");
```

But this also fails.
So where is the variable `uuid_`?
Because when I print out all variables in the console of the current `somePet` with a Serializer, I get something like

```
* cat.uuid_ = 34d7a781-472d-4d98-861e-7cff08045445;
```

or

```
* dog.foo = 1
* dog.uuid_ = 34d7a781-472d-4d98-861e-7cff08045445;
```

in the console.
So the variable `uuid_` is there with a default value.
(I am using the serializer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719621/5229688))

So how do I get the `uuid_` variable in my java snippet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no such `Serializer` under the the package `java.util`, so you're using something else.

An `trait` is translated to a Java `interface`, which **cannot have fields** per se.
However you're trying to access the field via the `Pet` interface

```
pet.class.getField(...)
```

That won't work. You need to look for the field inside the concrete `class`.
Also, the field will be `private` by default, since the access is granted via a `getter`.

The `getField` method is able to retrieve every `public` field for the entire class hierarchy (which mean even superclasses), while `getDeclaredField` is able to retrieve `protected` and `private` fields, but only on the exact class you're calling it from. You need also a call to `setAccessible(true)`, because

> A value of true indicates that the reflected object should suppress
>   Java language access checking when it is used. A value of false indicates that the reflected object should enforce Java language access checks

The correct code would be (`dog` is the concrete instance)

```
final Field uuid = dog.getClass().getDeclaredField("uuid_");
uuid.setAccessible(true);
final Object o = uuid.get(dog);
```

Or using the automatic `getter`

```
final Method uuid = dog.getClass().getMethod("uuid_");
final Object o = uuid_.invoke(dog);
```

Comment: I'd mention the difference for `getDeclaredField` vs `getField`

Comment: that's greate, thanks. Did not know the difference between `getDeclaredField` and `getField`.