# Eval function in Dalvik

Tags: android, eval

If I know a variable's pattern such as R.id.edit_x where x (1..N), how can I get a reference to a given EditText, like findViewByID(R.id.edit_1). Is there something like an "eval" function in Dalvik ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Java reflection. Discussion on retrieving static final fields via reflection is here -  [Accessing Java static final ivar value through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850148/accessing-java-static-final-ivar-value-through-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

hoha's answer is good. Another thing you can do is create a look-up table that maps 1..N to the resource IDs. (Presumably you know all the resource IDs ahead of time.)

Comment: Actually the EditTexts are created programmatically so no IDs are previously known.

Answer (score 0):

maybe， you can check [roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice). it is a ioc framework for android and it's realy easy to use. i copy some code from the sample from the project to show how to use it:

```
public class AstroboyMasterConsole extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.self_destruct) Button selfDestructButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.say_text)      EditText sayText;
    @InjectView(R.id.brush_teeth)   Button brushTeethButton;
    @InjectView(tag="fightevil")    Button fightEvilButton;     // we can also use tags if we want

}
```

then you can you these injected variables in your code！