# Reflectively accessing final static variable without initialization

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to access a bunch of final static public ints from a class using reflection.  This class however doesn't have a constructor - e.g. the android R.id .  I am trying to get all int values for these, however I can't seem to access it due to the fact that you can't create the class.  I was thinking of possible extending it just to create a constructor, but I am unsure this is wise.  Any suggestions?  I can't modify R.id or R.array (at least I shouldn't I think).

Thanks in advanced!
Jon

Comment: You don't need a constructor to access static variables.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850148/accessing-java-static-final-ivar-value-through-reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's all you need:

```
Field field = R.id.class.getField("some_var");
int value = field.getInt(null);
```

Comment: The point is that you can pass "null" to the get methods to access static members.

Comment: Thanks!  I have tried that, but I get a null pointer exception, let me get the code and post it... thanks!