# To find the references of a variable in all classes of a jar

Tags: java, reflection, netbeans

How to find the all references of a static variable in all classes of a jar through reflection...

guess any one have any Idea...

(similar to find usage option in netbeans)

thanks in advance....

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you are looking for can be found using below two posts...one is to access all static fields of class...and other is to get all classes of package...

[Find classes of package using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

[Static field access through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850148/accessing-java-static-final-ivar-value-through-reflection)

Comment: Amit, Those are to find the objects or variables on a class and to find the classes on a sub modules...

actually i'm looking for...
referneces (say if i searched for a static variable name "var1", such that i have to get all the classes on the jar where ever i used the static variable)